# Synonymize [dog] with [dogs]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Some idiot (who happens to look a lot like me) keeps creating/using a [dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dog) tag instead of using [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs) forcing someone to edit it to [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs) (and given the limited numbers of full edit users, we require the OP and the community team to have to approve these edits)

Since this is likely going to be an on going issue in the future of the site with singular and plural versions of the animals, can we synonymize them now so it doesn't keep getting recreated and used?

There is also a [cat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) tag, but that one isn't my fault.  Can we synonymize it with [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats)

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/a/66) for some discussion on synonyms for singular and plural tags.

Comment: @BenMiller its a dup then.  I missed that one since the title really didn't address the singular/plural issue.

Comment: @Skippy not deleting... just needs to be a dup